# Flash via iframe in Safari is breaking

Tags: javascript, css, flash, safari

I'm trying to load an iframe into a div via ajax. The iframe serves Flash content.

There are four divs (above each other) with the same Flash-through-iframe implementation, and I show and hide these divs to correspond with the user's navigation. This works well, except in Safari. I triple-checked my JavaScript that toggles the divs (using `display: none` and `display: show`), but it doesn't work in Safari. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like serving ajax-loaded Flash in an iFrame is a recipe for disaster to start with.

Without an example, all I can find a problem with is your use of `display: show` because `show` is not a valid value. Perhaps `display: none` and `display: block` instead?

CSS Display Property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Oh ya that's what i am using.. disaplay:block and none.. in rush i said show.. and Flash via ajax is the requirement- to load the page initially with one frame and load the rest in background...  It seems like my Flash object is not hiding when i set the display:none for parent Div...

Comment: I'm not sure how else to help, but you might get more answers if you provided an example for the good folks on Stack Overflow.